# MVVMCross Table View Animations

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using MVVMCross and I'm trying to use the UITableView Row animations with the following code:

```
        NotesTableSource source = new NotesTableSource(TableView, NoteListCell.Identifier, (NoteListViewModel) ViewModel)
        {
            UseAnimations = true,
            AddAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimation.Top,
            RemoveAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimation.Top,
            ReplaceAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimation.Top,
        };
```

NotesTableSource is a subclass of MvxStandardTableViewSource.
The table view and bindings are working fine, but I can't see any animations occurring when the viewmodel changes.

It seems like setting those properties would do the trick, but it's not. Am I missing something?

Thank You!!

Comment: How is your list changing? is it an observable collection? This sample works for single add/remove changes - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/MonoTouchCellTutorial/MonoTouchCellTutorial/UI/Views/PetShopView.cs